# SSRS 2008 R2 - Repeat textbox/table on all pages

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a report in SSRS which basically contains a table of dates and blank columns for users to print and then manually write data into.

The report has a @FromDate and a @ToDate parameter as well as a @Location parameter.

The @FromDate and @ToDate parameters are used to populate a table with dates and is grouped per week (Mon to Sun) with a few extra columns that are blank for manually writing data. Above this table there is a textbox containing employee name.

What I am trying to do is to get the employee name to change for every page according to the @Location parameter. So if a location has 10 employees I need 10 pages with the different employees names at the top so 1 page per employee. The main table with the dates should repeat but the data will be exact on each page, basically the only thing that will be changing is the employee name at the top of the report.

Currently I have tried creating a table with just a header and adding the employeename field into the header but it only returns the 1st employee within the dataset and only returns 1 page when there should be 26.

What would be the best way to achieve this? It seems simple enough in theory but can't get it to do what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A rough outline:

1. Create a subreport that shows your calendar. It will take the two date parameters.
2. Create a parent report.
3. The dataset in the parent should return a list of Employees for the selected location.
4. Create a table for that dataset, and put two detail rows in that table. The first will just have Employee name.
5. Test at this point and see that you just get a list of employees.
6. Place your subreport in the second detail row, and set the parameters to be handed through.
7. Change the properties of the detail group to have a page break between instances.

If you let us know what isn't working for you, we can give more specific advice.

Comment: Excellent, that was the solution I was looking for, was a more difficult task than first expected, great guide, thanks!